# Eclipse juno Build error with hello world project

Tags: java, eclipse

I am  very new to android programming. and started recently using Eclipse Juno with Win7 and I think its the latest release I have. downloaded Android SDK also.with all the updates and packages.

Now, while I am creating a new project with a simple way of creating a new project in eclipse, (it usually becomes the hello world program with blank template selection) and in file MainActivity.java
It gives the following error :

```
--> .R cannot be resolved to a variable MainActivity.java
```

I cant understand why this is happening. can someone help ..please

(I cant post picture as I am new)

thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible for us to see the code?

Comment: Do a clean then build.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project if problem do not solve then watch the **Problems bar** aligned aside of "console" and "logcat". I think it will be a problem with your project's resource like somewhere in your layout files or drawables or menus or values files or in Menifext file.
Also watch your java code **imports**. They should contain the import containing **R** like android.R or something like that. If they contanins it then remove that import and clean again. Your problem will be solved.